# SSIS - For each loop not stopping

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I make For Each Loop container to store file name (from directory) to SQL table. It works fine until i put it inside Execute Task.
My problem is, after put it inside `Execute Task`, the `For Each Loop` container run forever (non stop loop) and it is not going to the next process.

Below is the For Each Loop Container and I put it inside the execute package task on picture 2

I use variable in For Each Loop to store the files directory and insert it on table using `Execute SQL Task`
[image: Execute Package Task]
[image]

[image: For Each Loop]

Is there some setting or properties need to set?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a parent/child package setup in the bottom screenshot. The first one, all we know is it's a ForEach Loop Container and you have a script task inside it. What Variables are being processed in the FELC and what is your Script Task?

Comment: @billinkc variable I used in FELC is directory where I saved the FIles. And the `Execute SQL Task` is insert statement for the directory and file names. I already updated the picture above